# How can I repair damaged gloss of hardwood floor due to spilled scented oil?

Tags: repair, flooring, hardwood-floor, damage

I spilled scented oil on my glossy hardwood floor and left it unattended for a few hours. After I cleaned up the spill, the spot had turned white. I researched online and found that applying a mixture of baking soda + linseed oil should take care of it. It definitely did bring the color back to brown but the spot has lost its glossiness. How can I restore the gloss?

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to know what the floor was finished with. If it was factory finished, it was probably a lacquer finish. If it was a stick built hardwood and finished after install, it is probably urethane.  Regardless, if you gently sand the edges around the damaged area, you should be able to brush in some gloss oil based urethane.  Feather it out very thinly into the existing good finish.  It may not be perfect, but should come close.

Comment: A great deal of prefinished flooring now comes with a very hard urethane finish. Many manfuacturers offer repair kits with small bottles of finish tha may solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

find out what the finish is ie, Latex poly, oil based poly. Sand the top coat from the area from board to board making sure to stop at the length and width of entire portion that is damaged. Apply a sealer coat, lightly sand till smooth and re-poly. Its a good idea to lay low tack tape at edges so you dont overlap.